# Selecting two colums in two tables (one column being the same in both tables)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables - category and subcategory, they both have id_category.
In other words, in **category**:

```
id_category: 3
category_name: Security
```

And in **subcategory**:

```
id_subcategory: 1
id_category: 3
subcategory_name: Antivirus
```

I have multiple items in the same category, so I want it to list the items like this:
Security: Antivirus, Spyware, Firewall.

Also, I want it to do the same with other categories, so in the end it will list like this:
Security: Antivirus, Spyware, Firewall.
Multimedia: Audio, Video, Images.

I'm not sure how to do that. I searched around and tried different things but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT
  category_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory_name)
FROM
  category INNER JOIN subcategory
  ON subcategory.id_category=category.id_category
GROUP BY
  category_name
```

See fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c8b3/1).

Comment: Thanks, it does its job. But if I wanted to display the subcategories in new rows, then I suppose I should use the explode function in php?

Comment: @AlejandraUzelac to split a string you can use explode, but you could also use a different separator instead of the comma, like GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory_name SEPARATOR '<br>') or you can also join the two tables without using GROUP_CONCAT/GROUP BY and fetch all the rows..

Comment: I know this is way off topic, but if I was to create a list of links, like Security: antivirus, spyware and so on, and every subcategory is a different link, how can I do that? The code should look like this: `<h2>Security</h2> <ul><li><a href="#">subcat1</a></li> <li><a href="#">subcat2</a></li></ul>`. I tried using `foreach` on the subcategories but it still displays them as one link.

Comment: I also thouth of using separator: `SEPARATOR '</a></li><li><a href=\"#\">'` but then it would only work with the second subcategory. Is there any way I could wrap a subcategory in that `<li>` element?

Comment: @AlejandraUzelac as a quick solution, you could use `CONCAT('<li><a href=\"#\">', GROUP_CONCAT(subcategory_name SEPARATOR '</a></li><li><a href=\"#\">'), '</a></li>')`, if your list is small it should work!